# Recursive Transpose of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Input:

```
|Name|L1|L1 Desc|L2|L2 Desc|L3|L3 Desc|L4|L4 Desc|
|Name1|L1|L1 Desc|L2|L2 Desc|L3|L3 Desc|L4|L4 Desc|
|Name2|L1|L1 Desc|L2|L2 Desc|L3|L3 Desc|L4|L4 Desc|
```

I want to get:

```
|Name|Levels|Level Desc|
|Name1|L1|L1 Desc|
|Name1|L2|L2 Desc|
|Name1|L3|L3 Desc|
|Name1|L4|L4 Desc|
|Name2|L1|L1 Desc|
|Name2|L2|L2 Desc|
|Name2|L3|L3 Desc|
|Name2|L4|L4 Desc|
```

etc

However, it should also expand to fit multiple Descs(see Kid below) as per some manual input criteria (like a function parameter), for example:

```
|Name|L1|L1 Desc|L1 Kid|L2|L2 Desc|L2 Kid|L3|L3 Desc|L3 Kid|L4|L4 Desc|L4 Kid|
|Name1|L1|L1 Desc|L1 Kid|L2|L2 Desc|L2 Kid|L3|L3 Desc|L3 Kid|L4|L4 Desc|L4 Kid|
|Name2|L1|L1 Desc|L1 Kid|L2|L2 Desc|L2 Kid|L3|L3 Desc|L3 Kid|L4|L4 Desc|L4 Kid|
```

so that it becomes

```
|Name|Levels|Level Desc|Level Kid|
|Name1|L1|L1 Desc|L1 Kid|
|Name1|L2|L2 Desc|L2 Kid|
|Name1|L3|L3 Desc|L3 Kid|
|Name1|L4|L4 Desc|L4 Kid|
|Name2|L1|L1 Desc|L1 Kid|
|Name2|L2|L2 Desc|L2 Kid|
|Name2|L3|L3 Desc|L3 Kid|
|Name2|L4|L4 Desc|L4 Kid|
```

etc

Typically I would use `pd.melt` to do this, but in this case, it does not fulfill what I require.

Is there a pandas function for me to do this, where I can state the level of cuts I wish to take (Modulo 2 or Modulo 3 for example or outline the fields I want to keep and the column fields to fall into them)
Or I will have to do this via recursively modified `pd.melt` in a custom function?

**Note: I do not know the column names in advance. I will only know by how many (every 2/3/4/5/6/etc Levels) I have to split by**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert first columns to index for only repeating columns, then grouping by modulo, set default columns names by `range` and `concat` together, last set columns names by first group for general solution:

```
n = 3
df = df.set_index('Name')
df1 = pd.concat([g.set_axis(range(len(g.columns)), axis=1, inplace=False) 
        for i, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns)) // n , axis=1)], ignore_index=False)
df1.columns = df.columns[:n]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
    Name  L1  L1 Desc  L1 Kid
0  Name1  L1  L1 Desc  L1 Kid
1  Name2  L1  L1 Desc  L1 Kid
2  Name1  L2  L2 Desc  L2 Kid
3  Name2  L2  L2 Desc  L2 Kid
4  Name1  L3  L3 Desc  L3 Kid
5  Name2  L3  L3 Desc  L3 Kid
6  Name1  L4  L4 Desc  L4 Kid
7  Name2  L4  L4 Desc  L4 Kid
```

Comment: Im not exactly following this solution. Could you elaborate more on how I can change it to fit additional column increases? Particularly instead of by every 2, it becomes by every 3,4,5 etc?

Comment: @ycx - What are columns names? Is possible split them by first whitespace in real data?

Comment: I won't be able to determine the exact name of the column, but I can determine the number of columns per increase.

Comment: I've finally had the time to look through this and use it effectively. I'm still not fully following it but it does solve the problem posed. Thanks!